# Streaming realtime video

Tags: video, vlc, streaming, gstreamer

I'm trying to stream realtime video from gstreamer under Ubuntu to VLC under Windows. Gstreamer is started via script:

`v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw,width=320,height=240,framerate=30/1 ! jpegenc quality=85 ! rtpjpegpay ! udpsink host=x.x.x.x port=xxxx sync=false`

and VLC uses option `:network-caching=0`. Both PC are connected to the same Wi-Fi hotspot. Sometimes stream demonstrates very pretty delay (less than 300ms), but sometimes delay grows up to 20 seconds. What can cause such a terrible delay and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: ever get to the bottom of this? I am having the same issue, and I am not sure if the problem is sender or receiver

Comment: @matt no luck with VLC. Now using gstreamer for Windows  as receiver. No more growing delay.